# Hiding a UINavigationBar after hitting back button

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have 3 view controllers and they are all chained together like so:

```
vc1 -> vc2 -> vc3
```

In view controller 1 and 2, I have the navigation bar hidden like so:

```
elf.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

The third view controller shows the navigation bar and has a back button on the left. When I hit the back button it goes to view controller 2 but the navigation bar is no longer hidden. How do I hide it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple code in Third view controller

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I recommend using the animated flag from the appear methods instead of always using YES. Like: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated]; This will make it work well if the view controller is presented animated or not.

Answer (score 1):

write this code in viewWillAppear method in viewController1 and viewController2

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Thanks